# Best method to sketch dimensions and obtain area of shape drawn

Tags: javascript, svg, draw, area, dimension

I'm trying to develop a very simple sketch program that can draw the dimensions of buildings. For example, if I want to draw a 24'x24' house, it would simply be a square with each side representing 24'. I've read that SVG/Javascript may be ideal, but I'm looking for some specific guidance.

Here is a link to a 30 second video showing exactly what I need: https://vid.me/96Mz

I'm able to draw those shapes by clicking in one spot and then moving the mouse to another location to draw a wall, then click again to produce a third corner, and then a final time to close the shape. I'd need the area to be calculated too.Preferably the dimensions of each side would be able to be shown as labels.

Here's an example of an image I'd like to be possible:

[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HDjQ.png)

Can you think of anything to help me build a simple version? Any feedback is huge, thanks a lot.

Comment: If you wanna go *way* more general and allow free closed shapes, monte carlo estimator would be a good way to go...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'free closed shapes'. I need to be able to draw angles and calculate areas. I'll check out monte carlo though thanks!

Comment: Let me be more precise: http://commons.bcit.ca/math/entertainment/monte/

Comment: Just to add another option, if you have simple polygons, which I think is more related to your question, you can find a triangulation and sum the areas of each triangle. (https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs235/Triangulation.pdf)

Comment: @FábioDias, thank you for your help! I really appreciate it. These topics are way over my head so I'll need to really dedicate some time to understand.